# Android how to append new data to a Custom base adapter

Tags: android, listview, append

I have a custom base adapter that extracts new data from the database on Button Click, it works however the old data is discarded and I would like to keep it and append the new data to it. I was looking over this example [how to append latest data to custom base adapter list view in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596012/how-to-append-latest-data-to-custom-base-adapter-list-view-in-android) and it seems incomplete, for instance how can I append the new data to the old one without creating a new object.

This is the area of my code that I am struggling with

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        CustomView CV;
        try {
            ListView lv = (ListView) m.findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
            JSONObject jsonn = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArray = jsonn.getJSONArray("myarray");
            JSONObject jobject = null;
            JSONArray sss = new JSONArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                jobject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                jobject.getString("message");
                sss.put(jobject);
            }

            jsonn.put("myarray", sss);
            if(data==1)
            {
            CV = new CustomView(jsonn, m);
            DMF.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.setAdapter(CV);
        }
            else
            {
    // New data should be appended here
             CV = new CustomView(jsonn, m);
            DMF.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.setAdapter(CV);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
            System.err.println();
        }

    }
```

I can not figure out how to append the new data and not create a new object. The data integer will equal 1 on first pass and 2 on the other pass. I as stated before can not seem to figure how to append like on what this post is stating
[how to append latest data to custom base adapter list view in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596012/how-to-append-latest-data-to-custom-base-adapter-list-view-in-android)

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9596167/850347

As they said, 1) define this adapter andnewmsgResult at top of your class..not a local variable inside a class.

2) update the values/data in newmsgResult and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Thanks looked over it and it helped me solve the issue.